# lost all projects from eclipse all java and xml files on workspace have 0kb how to restore

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

I am using eclipse juno -adt tool Eclipse Platform **Version: 4.2.1**.

i lost all projects from eclipse project explorer .they doesnt have single line of code. all projects in work space folder have 0kb data(user/workplace). is it possible to restore the complete projects from .metdata or work space runtime.

```
cd ~/Documents/workspace/.metalog/.plugins
rm -rf  org.eclipse.core.resources
```

i have tried above commands but **rm** is not recognized .how can i setup path for eclipse.. please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get it back, ask experts if you still don't get you may try this, there is 50% chance that you may get .java files atleast.

1) Download  [recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download)

2) Open recuva and select All contents.

3) Locate the path to your workspace.

4) "Deep scan" that may take hours, when you get all the deleted data back, extract .java,  .xml files from them.

5) Create a new workspace and add those files, and you can reprogram Manifist files manually. (If you are working on android)

Answer (score 0):

Try manually separating metadata for each package from the metadata folder in your workspace. Once you do that put the corresponding metadata and packages to a separate folder and then in your eclipse choose workspace window select the folder which you created for individual packages. It'll work. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced the same problem. The entire project displays all the files but they are all 0 bytes. Most recent bit bucket sync is not very recent. After cursing and kicking things, I had some luck with [recuva](http://recuva.com). Since it is an android project, I have the latest apk I had installed in my phone yesterday as I was doing the test, dex2Jar and JD-GUI helped a little her, but there are still mountains of code I will never get back.